# How to control the CSS of the contents that loaded dynamically into iframe?

Tags: jquery, html, css, iframe

I have tried to change the css of contents in the iframe.
i.e. I need to hide the `<img>` elements.
But I cannnot change..
Here is the sample code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <iframe src="http://www.carsales.com.au/pls/carsales/!dealer_content.welcome?dealer_id=10978" width="80%" height="600" id='frameDemo'></iframe> 

<script>
  $("#frameDemo").contents().find("img").css("display", "none");
</script>



</body>

</html>
```

Please help me

Kind regards
Niao Jina

Comment: [Same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript)

Comment: Yep. It's a CORS issue, but do please replace `.css('display', 'none')` with `.hide()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**If the iframe source is yours to control:**

The simple answer is that you need to treat the iframe as a seperate webpage entirely, because really, it is exactly that. It should have its own CSS/JS files and so forth, which would allow you manipulate it as needed.

If you are looking to manipulate it in a more dynamic way, you can append a variable to the iframe src URL (much like your dealer_id that is already there) then use JS to check for the variables value/existence and add a specific class to your images accordingly.

**example structure for iframe source**

iframe-content.html?imgvar=hide

iframe-style.css - define hide style here (eg: .hide{display:none;})

iframe-script.js - use this to check for variable in the src URL, and add hide class to img if it exists.

Comment: Dear Dayne
Thanks for your help.

But, I confused about your explain.
Could you send me the sample code?

If you create the sample code for me, I am very thanks for you.

My Email : jjstar215@gmail.com

I'm looking forward your help!

Best regards
Niao Jina

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of problems there.

The *main* problem is that you're running into the [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). You don't have script access to the content of a frame from a different origin than the page your script is running in.

If the frame's content were from the same origin, You'd want to wait for the `load` event on the frame's content. Example: [Live Copy](http://jsbin.com/ufonim/1) | [Live Source](http://jsbin.com/ufonim/1/edit)

```
var frame = $("<iframe>");
frame.load(frameLoaded);
frame.attr("src", "http://jsbin.com/inanin/1");
frame.appendTo(document.body);

function frameLoaded() {
    frame.contents().find("img").hide();
}
```

But again, the *main* problem is the SOP.